# Problemas con una Query en wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Estoy haciendo una función para traer unos cursos para eso tengo un post type donde cargo los cursos y una taxonomía de marcas que le asigno a que curso pertenecen para mostrar esto tengo una sección que es un filtrador donde tengo que decirle que cursos se encuentran activo, para eso cree un campo customs fields selector para poner que curso se encuentra habilitado / no habilitado.
El problema es que cuando yo habilito desde backend un curso no me lo muestra.

El ejemplo se puede ver [aqui](http://qkdev.com.ar/camconnection/web/servicios/training-vero-software/) también adjunto una foto de como es el filtrador [image: imagen del ejemplo html]

La query es la siguiente;

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <div id="filter" class="animated fadeInDown bottomspace10">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected"><i class="icon icon-reorder"></i> Ver Todos</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".activo" title="¡Fechas Definidas!"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> Cursos Activos</a></li>
      <li>Líneas:</li>

      <?php 
         $terms = get_terms('categoria-cursos', get_queried_object());
         if($terms){

         foreach ($terms as $termino){ ?>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-filter=".id<?php echo $termino->term_id;?>"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> 
           <?php echo $termino->name; ?>
           </a>
      </li>

      <?php } }?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <?php if($terms){ //si existe contenido 

     foreach($terms as $termino){
      $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'curso',
       'showposts'=> -1,
       'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'categoria-cursos',
              'field' => 'id',
              'terms' => $termino->term_id
              )
          )
      );
      $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
     

       if($post){
        while($posts->have_posts()):
         $posts->the_post();
        $cur = $post;

         ?>
  <div class="boxportfolio1 bp-height item id<?php echo $termino->term_id;?> <?php  if(get_terms('curso_activo',$cur->ID) == 'habilitado'){echo 'activo';}?>">
    <!-- desde acá parte un bloque -->
    <div class="boxcontainer">
      <div class="prod-imagecontainer">
        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($cur->ID,'thumbnail'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cur->post_title; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="roll">
        <div class="wrapcaption">
          <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($cur->ID); ?>"><i class="icon-arrow-right captionicons"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="prod-infocontainer">
        <h1>
          <a href="vero-alphacam-router.html">
            <?php echo $cur->post_title; //este es tl titulo?>
          </a>

        </h1>
        <p>
          <?php echo get_the_content($cur->ID);?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;
       }
      ?>
  <?php } } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hola Alo como seria? que agregue eso decís?

Comment: se te están mezclando los loops me parece (`$post`en esa instancia referenciaría a la pagina o post actual) luego del `$posts->the_post();` ahi recien toma valores del último query y los mantiene hasta que hagas un reset, cual es el problema que aparece?

Comment: Osea la función en si anda http://qkdev.com.ar/camconnection/web/servicios/training-vero-software/ el problema es que yo desde back end con un selector customs le estoy diciendo si el curso esta habilitado o no, es ahí donde no me funciona. Nose si es aca el problema class="boxportfolio1 bp-height item id<?php echo $termino->term_id;?> <?php  if(get_terms('curso_activo',$cur->ID) == 'habilitado'){echo 'activo';}?>

Comment: prueba con `get_the_ID()` si es que la id no coincide, por otro lado `get_terms` te puede retornar un array asi que la comparación con un string puede fallar sería ese el problema?

Comment: bueno dale pruebo eso

Comment: version de wordpress?

Comment: WordPress 4.9.5

Comment: Para un post en específico, debes usar simplemente  [`has_term`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term). Por ejemplo: `if( has_term( 'habilitado', 'curso_activo' ) ) {
    echo 'activo';
}` Nótese que el primer parámetro que acepta es el valor `$term` que se busca, y el segundo es la taxonomía. Admite otro parámetro opcional, que sería el id del post, pero si estás en el loop (como supongo), no lo necesitarías. Si no funciona, le pasas ese tercer parámetro y listo.

Comment: Tendría entonces que reemplazar <?php if(get_terms('curso_activo',$cur->ID) == 'habilitado'){echo 'activo';}?>"> por esto que me pusiste decís? Solamente eso? O tendría que agregar algo más?

Comment: @A.Cedano Probe pero no me funciono.

Comment: Invirtiendo el orden de `habilitado` y `curso_activo` ¿tampoco funciona? ¿o agregando el parámetro del ID del post ?

Comment: Agregue if( has_term( 'habilitado', 'curso_activo' ) ) { echo 'activo'; } y nada, sino que otra opción me dabas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás utilizando [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) para llegar al valor del `custom field` donde almacenas si un curso está activo o no. El problema es que esta función devuelve un `array`de resultados y por lo tanto no puedes comparar el resulatdo obtenido como si se tratara de un `string`utilizando el operador `==`.

Una alternativa podría ser usando la función [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) que enviando el tercer parámetro como `true`devuelve un único valor en formato `string`.

Prueba cambiando esta línea:

```
<?php 
     if (get_terms('curso_activo',$cur->ID) == 'habilitado') {
     echo 'activo';
     } 
   ?>
```

Por esta:

```
<?php 
 if (get_post_meta('curso_activo', $cur->ID,true) === 'habilitado') {
     echo 'activo';
  } 
?>
```

Por último, y a modo de añadido, te aconsejo que desarrolles [en modo depuración](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: Perfecto Ernesto voy a probar lo que me decís y te cuento como me fue.

Comment: No me anduvo, nose si estoy fallando yo con algo de la query

Comment: Hola quería preguntarte si podrías ayudarme con este problema que tengo. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158357/problemas-para-traer-contenido-con-query-en-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Veo un poco extraño el uso de `get_terms` prueba esto:

```
<?php 
  $ct = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'curso_activo',
    'hide_empty' => true,
  ]); 
  // var_dump($ct); <-- descomentar para ver que devuelve get_terms
  if (!empty($ct)&&in_array('habilitado', $ct))
  {echo 'activo';}
  ?>">
```

Comment: Esto lo pondría dentro del <div id="content"> decis?

Comment: era para reemplazar la línea `<?php  if(get_terms('curso_activo',$cur->ID) == 'habilitado'){echo 'activo';}?>">` pero también me parece que la forma que propone @a-cedano sería menos enroscada

Comment: Probé pero no funciono.

Comment: ya anduvo!! gracias!

Comment: Hola @aloMalbarez quería preguntarte si podrías ayudarme con este problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158357/problemas-para-traer-contenido-con-query-en-wordpress

Comment: Hola Alo queria preguntarte si puedes darme una ayuda con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159775/tengo-un-problema-para-traer-unos-cursos-de-un-post-type-a-un-page-en-wordpress