# Problemas para traer contenido con Query en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sql, wordpress-theme

Estoy teniendo un problema con este sitio [web](http://qkdev.com.ar/camconnection/web/curso/edgecam-standard-milling/) en la parte de TODOS LOS CURSOS. 
Estoy queriendo traer en el listado desplegable todos los cursos que voy cargando en un Post Type llamado curso, Para eso asigné unas taxonomías (Edgecam. Radan, Apahacam) donde le digo a que marca pertenece dicho curso. 
Por ejemplo la url que adjunto Edgecam Standard Milling que es un curso pertenece a Edgecam. 
Si bien los títulos de los desplegables están bien puestos, no sé como traer los títulos de los post con su dicho enlace.

El código que armé es el siguiente:

```
<?php

$terms = get_terms(
  array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'categoria-cursos',
    'parent'     => get_queried_object()->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false,
  )
);

foreach ($terms as $termino) {

  $posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
      'showposts' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'cursos',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'categoria-cursos',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => $termino->name,
        )
      )
    )
  );
  $posts_array = get_posts($posts_array);
  if($posts_array){

    ?>
    <div id="accordion-container">
      <h2 class="accordion-header ">
        <?php echo $termino->name; ?>
      </h2>
      <div class="accordion-content" >
        <ul class="icons longarrowlist">
          <?php foreach ($posts_array as $termino): ?>
            <li>
              <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($termino); ?>">
                <b class="colortext">
                  <?php echo $termino->post_title; ?>
                </b>
              </a>
            </li>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres es listar todos los posts que pertenecen a cada categoría. Y que `$termino` toma los valores (Edgecam. Radan, Apahacam). ¿es así?

Comment: Exacto! seria traer los post que voy subiendo y a que marca pertenece ese curso.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución podría ser que por cada término cuyo valor va tomando la variable `$termino` busques sus posts relacionados con la función `get_posts()`.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como podría ser esta consulta, faltaría que iteraras sobre el array de resultados de la consulta de posts para listarlos de la forma que te convenga.

```
<?php

$terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'categoria-cursos',
        'parent'     => get_queried_object()->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);



foreach ($terms as $termino) {

    $posts_array = get_posts(
        array( 'showposts' => -1,
               'post_type' => 'curso',
               'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'categoria-cursos',
                       'field' => 'name',
                       'terms' => $termino->name,
                   )
               )
        )
    );?>

/*La variable $posts_array  debería ser un array con todos los posts 

relacionados, sólo tue quedaría iterar para listarlos*/

    <div id="accordion-container">
        <h2 class="accordion-header ">
            <?php echo $termino->name; ?>
        </h2>
        <div class="accordion-content" >
            <ul class="icons longarrowlist">
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($termino); ?>">
                        <b class="colortext">
                            <?php the_sub_field('texto'); ?>
                        </b>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**NOTA** No he podido probar la consulta puesto que no dispongo de la estructura de posts que te has construido en tu web y me es imposible reproducirla.

Comment: y te hago una pregunta en esta etiqueta <b class="colortext">                            <?php the_sub_field('texto'); ?></b> no seria un custom fields sino mas bien traería el titulo del Post osea el titulo del curso.

Comment: Por ej en los <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($termino); ?>"> los trae bien porque serian las taxonomias que hace referencia dicho cursos.

Comment: Digamos que así tendrías disponible toda la info de cada post. En la cabecera del accordion pondrías el nombre de la taxonomía y dentro un listado con el título de cada post enlazado al propio post.

Comment: Claro eso es lo que nose! como llamar a cada post que se va agregando y que este relacionado a dicha taxonomía.

Comment: http://qkdev.com.ar/camconnection/web/curso/edgecam-standard-milling/ edite lo de arriba el código, el problema es que estoy haciendo mal algo y me esta trayendo hasta los Post de las noticias.

Comment: Has comprobado que los posts estén bien etiquetados?

Comment: emmm si el problema es que no se si estoy haciendo bien este llamado  $posts_array = get_posts($posts_array);        if($posts_array){

Comment: Parece que no, en mi ejemplo se supone que `$posts_array`contiene un array de posts pertenecientes a tipo 'cursos' cuya taxonomía 'categoria-cursos' se corresponde con al valor de `$termino` en esa iteración del bucle. ¿has comprobado que sea así? haz un `print_r()`y visualiza el contenido a ver...

Comment: Ok! al print_r( ) que le tendría que indicar?

Comment: prueba así: `print_r($posts_array);`

Comment: Probe con lo que vos me pasaste y agregue eso y nada che!

Comment: No pense que era tan complicado

Comment: Quieres decir que la consulta no ha devuelto ningún post?

Comment: No nada!  pero sera porque tiene esto? <?php the_sub_field('texto'); ?> que no tiene nada que ver porque ese custom field no existe mas