# Tengo un problema para traer unos cursos de un Post Type a un page en wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql, wordpress-theme

Hola estoy haciendo esta pagina [web](http://qkdev.com.ar/camconnection/web/servicios/training-vero-software/) en donde tengo unos cursos que los subo directamente en Post type cursos pero los tengo que filtrar en esta pagina que adjunto arriba.
El sitio esta hecho para dos países Mexico y argentina y necesito que las personas de Mexico vean exclusivamente los cursos de su pais? Para eso use un plugin llamado GeoIP Detection para obtener el ID en este caso de Mexico y una función que es esta que resalto

```
function estoy_en_mexico(){
    $ipinfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    if ($ipinfo) {
        return $ipinfo->country->isoCode === 'MX'; // en realidad deberia ir MX y no AR
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Pues bien lo que necesito ahora, es generar un función en la pagina que adjunto que es la que filtra los cursos y toma tanto titulo imagen destacada y content, para que cuando una persona navegue en dicho país pueda ver los curso que le corresponden a dicho pais. 
Yo al post type curso le genere un check para decirle este curso pertenece a mexico por ej. Lo que me esta faltando es filtrar los cursos por países ya que en la sección que adjunte arriba se ven todos.

*El codigo del filtrado de cursos es el siguiente:*

```
<div class="col-md-8 animated fadeInLeft notransition">
  <h2 class="smalltitle">
    <span>Nuestros Cursos</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <div id="filter" class="animated fadeInDown bottomspace10">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected"><i class="icon icon-reorder"></i> Ver Todos</a></li>

          <li><a href="#" data-filter=".activo" title="¡Fechas Definidas!"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> Cursos Activos</a></li>

          <li>Líneas:</li>

          <?php 
                $terms = get_terms('categoria-cursos', get_queried_object());
                if($terms){

        foreach ($terms as $termino){ ?>
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".id<?php echo $termino->term_id;?>"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> 
            <?php echo $termino->name; ?>
            </a>
          </li>

          <?php } }?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END filtering menu -->

  <div id="content">
    <?php if($terms){ //si existe contenido 

        foreach($terms as $termino){
            $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'curso',
                            'showposts'=> -1,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'categoria-cursos',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => $termino->term_id
                                )
                            )
                        );
                        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );


                            if($post){
                                while($posts->have_posts()):
                                    $posts->the_post();
                                $cur = $post;

                                    ?>
    <div class="boxportfolio1 bp-height item id<?php echo $termino->term_id;?> <?php if (get_field('curso_activo', $cur->ID,true) == 'habilitado') { echo 'activo'; }?>">

      <!-- desde acá parte un bloque -->
      <div class="boxcontainer">
        <div class="prod-imagecontainer">
          <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($cur->ID,'thumbnail'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cur->post_title; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="roll">
          <div class="wrapcaption">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($cur->ID); ?>"><i class="icon-arrow-right captionicons"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prod-infocontainer">
          <h1>
            <a href="vero-alphacam-router.html">
              <?php echo $cur->post_title; //este es tl titulo?>
            </a>

          </h1>
          <p>
            <?php echo get_the_content($cur->ID);?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;
                            }
                        ?>
    <?php } } ?>

  </div>

</div>
```

> la llamada que hago al single de curso para decir si el curso es de mexico o no es:

```
<?php if(estoy_en_mexico() && !get_field('cursos_mexico')){
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
    } ?>
```

Comment: como se llama el campo check para decirle al post que está disponible en mexico?

Comment: si ahi te digo, se llama "cursos_mexico"

Comment: Yo ese check lo asigne en el post de los curso que es desde ahi donde ellos le asignan si ese curso pertenece a mexico o argentina y general.

Comment: El ultimo fragmento que yo puse ahí como ejemplo es que si por ejemplo la persona que esta mexico por esas casualidades encuentra la url de uno de los cursos que no serian para mexico en google y quiere acceder, directamente lo va a mandar a la pagina 404 y no va a poder ver el contenido.

Comment: Pero se comprende lo que estoy queriendo no?

Comment: ahora ya no entiendo =P, como filtrar los cursos con el checkbox? o como bloquear los cursos solo para mexico entrando desde otros países? son 2 es la primera, es la segunda?

Comment: Claro yo lo que use fue un plugin llamado GeoIP Detection y cree una funcion para obtener la iD de mexico, El sitio tiene dos sedes una en argentina y otra en mexico, entonces hay cursos que solamente van ser exclusivos para mexico, para eso con la función mas un custom fields que es un check cuando suben un post de cursos le dicen este curso pertenece a mexico? o se va a visualizar solo en mexico a la ves estos post tienen relacion con el filtrado del sitio que adjunte que es de donde traer el contenido ahi tampoco deberia mostrarse el curso en caso de que fuese de mexico. se comprende?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo en la query el filtro (por lo general el checkbox activado guarda un valor 1 si no le especificas otro)

```
 'meta_key'     => 'cursos_mexico',
 'meta_value'   => '1'
```

Comment: a ver pruebo eso

Comment: No no me anduvo pero, vos sabes que estoy probado asignado un curso para q se vea solo en mexico y tampoco me esta andando la función en el single-curso.php <?php if(estoy_en_mexico() && !get_field('cursos_mexico')){....    } ?>  Esta funcion yo la asigne despues de la etiqueta del header solamente agregue eso mas el custom field del check que es un verdadero/falso y la funcion del functions pero nada mas y se ve que antes andaba y ahora ya no. hay una extension de chrome muy buena para ver eso que se llama Unlimited Free VPN - Hola pero lo que me pasaste tampoco anduvo.

Comment: Quizas este mal el <?php if(estoy_en_mexico() && !get_field('cursos_mexico')){ porque es como que no me responde a nada por mas que clickee o no el campo